# Rails 2.3.8 Gem to whitelist ip addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a rails 2.3.8 app in which i want to whitelist ip addresses. Is there any gem to whitelist ip addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the gem [rack-ip-whitelist](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-ip-whitelist).

The source for this gem is available which has in it -

> "Rack Middleware for websites that need to contain access to a group
>   of ip addresses (a whitelist). Outside these addresses, vistors are
>   shown 403 Forbidden page."

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack-ip-whitelist/0.0.2/frames